# Pass local variable to html tag

Tags: angular

In Angular .ts file I have variable:

```js
var1 = "https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink";
```

I want to do something like this in .html file in same Angular component:

```html
<iframe [src]="var1"></iframe>
```

I have tried `{{var1}}` instead of var1 but it isn't working.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` for your url

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Set iframe source';
  url: string = "https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the `DomSanitizer` without a constructor parameter? Something like an annotated field `class { @Inject(DomSanitizer) sanitizer; }`?

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ No. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services

Comment: @JBNizet Was this supported in the past? I looked here but this doesn't seem to have been documented for JS: https://v2.angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Comment: No. Angular has always used constructor injection. https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#prep-for-injection

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. First thing I encounter that isn't possible from JavaScript. Even to use `injector.get()`, one needs to get a reference to the injector